# Write excel report using groovy step in SOAPUI for an automated Test Case which iterates 3 times

Tags: groovy, automation, automated-tests, soapui, jxl

I am trying to automate Webservice execution using soapui (groovy scripting).
I have the following TestSteps:

1. Data Source (Reads rows from and excel datasource)
2. Properties
3. SOAP Step
4. Capture SOAP REQ-RES as xml files
5. Generate Excel Report with xml
   tag value parsed from response
6. Looper (Iterate the Test Case for
   Total Rows in datasource excel file)

I have been successful in creating the framework but stuck in 5th step.

Step 5 executes successfully but creates report excel file having response data of only the last test iteration. A new workbook is created with each iteration which is overwritten by next iteration.

**Please suggest changes so as to implement the feature which apppends response data for every iteration in excel sheet**

I am using jxl api for writing parsed xml data using below code:

```
import jxl.*;

import com.eviware.soapui.support.XmlHolder

import jxl.write.*;


// create an excel workbook
WritableWorkbook workbook1=Workbook.createWorkbook(newFile("/Users/anant/Downloads/GroovyTest/report.xls"));

// create a sheet in the workbook
WritableSheet sheet1 = workbook1.createSheet("Report Worksheet", 0);

// Get the data to be added to the report
def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils( context )
def holder = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder("divide#response")

def fieldFromResponse = holder.getNodeValue("//n:divideResponse/n:Result")

// create a label 
Label label = new Label(0, 0, fieldFromResponse);
log.info fieldFromResponse

// Add the label into the sheet
sheet1.addCell(label); 
workbook1.write();
workbook1.close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one using apache poi.. Don't know much about jxl. 
Pls ignore the extra imports.. Modified the a code to suit your requirement :) - Here no creation of file, sheet etc. everytime, coz that was the problem in your code. And also there wasn't any row incrementer also.

```
   import java.io.*;
    import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
    import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
    import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
    import java.util.Iterator;

                // Pre requisite : create a property at testcase level as "rowIncrementer" with initial value 0 (0th row). This property will be used as row index
                //similar could be used for column also (cell). But i haven't used it now :)
                     def rowInc = testRunner.testCase.getPropertyValue("rowIncrementer")
                     rowInc = Integer.parseInt(rowInc)
                // accessing existing file
                    FileInputStream fIpStream= new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\excl.xls")); 

                    HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(fIpStream);
                      // accessing your existing sheet
                    HSSFSheet worksheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);

                    Row row = worksheet.createRow(rowInc);
                 //Create a new cell in current row
                 Cell cell = row.createCell(0);

                    cell.setCellValue("NewValue"+rowInc.toString());
                      //cell.setCellValue(fieldFromResponse)
                    fIpStream.close(); //Close the InputStream

                    FileOutputStream output_file =new FileOutputStream(new File("C:\\excl.xls"));  
                    wb.write(output_file);

                    output_file.close(); 

                // to increment the row for every loop -> will be incremented for every run of this teststep
                rowInc = rowInc + 1
                     testRunner.testCase.setPropertyValue("rowIncrementer", rowInc.toString())
```

Comment: Hope you have placed "rowInc" outside your script (suggest above is a testCase property). 
Because rowInc = rowInc + 1, needs to be stored somewhere and not to be initiated/stored in a variable within the script.

Comment: Yes. i have used as a testCase Property

Comment: Not sure why it isn't working for you.. I just used the same above code today and happens to work totally fine. Perhaps you could share your code.

Comment: Only change I made HSSF to XSSF and relevant changes

Answer (score 0):

Every time this executes it writes `fieldFromResponse` into cell A:1 (column 0, row 0). That's why you're only seeing the last test iteration.

You need to write to a different cell each time in order to keep each test iteration. Try this:

```
Label label = new Label(0, sheet1.rows, fieldFromResponse);
```

Comment: Thanks Emmanuel for prompt answer. I tried your solution but i am getting the same output Excel sheet with only last iteration result.

Comment: Workbook.createWorkbook() is for writing a new workbook, while Workbook.getWorkbook() is for reading an existing workbook. So basically a new workbook is being created every time. You've got to deal with an input and an output stream, and you can't have both open to the same file at the same time. You'd have the same issue with Apache POI. Maybe you can write to a temporary file and then rename it after closing the streams.

Comment: Yes that's the issue. Finally i modified the code and now I am simply creating a CSV file, in which is much easier to append data.